# Law of large numbers problem and calculation of max expected value

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, expectation, law-of-large-numbers

We've got to prove that $\frac{M_{n}}{\ln(n)}\rightarrow 1$ a.s. Where $M_{n}=\max\left\{{X_{1},...,X_{n}}\right\}$ , with $X_{i}\sim \mathrm{exp}(1)$ i.i.d. So it is obvious that we will have to use the Law of Large Numbers.

First I thought to rewrite it as $\frac{M_{n}}{n}\frac{n}{\ln(n)}$, and apply LLN for first fraction and take the limit for the second one, but $\frac{n}{\ln(n)}$ diverges.

My second thought was to calculate Cdf of $M_{n}$ and apply LLN for $S_{n}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}M_{k}$ and see if I take something like the following

$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{S_{n}}{n}\rightarrow \ln(n)$

But I don't know how to derive $\mathbb{E}(M_{n})$ (the cdf of $M_{n}$ is $(1-e^{-x})^{n}$ , for $x\geq 0$).

Im on the right track?? Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it is obvious that we will have to use the Law of Large Numbers.

The law of large numbers is usually related to *partial sums* of random variables, while here we have maximum.

Here are some hints to solve the problem.

1. Show that the series $\sum_n\mathbb P\left(\left\lvert \frac{M_{2^n}}{\log 2^n} -1 \right\rvert\gt \varepsilon             \right)$  is convergent for all positive $\varepsilon$. Using the Borel-Cantelli lemma, this will show that $ \frac{M_{2^n}}{\log 2^n} \to 1$ almost surely.
2. Let $R_N:= (M_{2^{N+ 1}}-M_{2^N})/\log 2^N      $. Show that $R_N\to 0$ almost surely by using the first part.
3. Conclude.

Answer (score 0):

Claim: $\mathbb{E}(M_n)=H_n$, the n-harmonic number ($H_n=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{i}$)

Proof: Let $Y_1,...,Y_n$ the order statistics of $(X_1,...,X_n)$, and then $Y_n=M_n$.

You can prove that $Y_1=\min\{X_i\}\sim \exp(n)$, and then $\mathbb{E}(Y_1)=\frac{1}{n}$.

Now, we use the memoryless property of exponential random variables. Essentially, “resets” the values of the other random variables, so that the time between $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ is the same as the time until the first of $n-1$ iid $\exp(1)$ random variables takes on a value $\mathbb{E}(Y_2-Y_1)=\frac{1}{n-1}$.

Inductively, $\mathbb{E}(M_n)=\mathbb{E}(Y_n)=\mathbb{E}\left(Y_1+\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} (Y_{i+1}-Y_i)\right)=H_n$